# How to random sort a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos

```
NSMutableString *str =@"abcdefg123";
```

I want random the every character to a new String like this @"f1ad2g3be2".

Comment: You should clarify your question. If you want to scramble the chars in the string, just do it yourself. Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: He wants to shuffle all the characters in a given string.

Comment: Next time ask question more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableString *str1 = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:str];
NSMutableString *str2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
while ([str1 length] > 0) {
    int i = arc4random() % [str1 length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i,1);
    NSString *sub = [str1 substringWithRange:range];
    [str2 appendString:sub];
    [str1 replaceOccurrencesOfString:sub withString:@"" options:nil range:range];
}

[str1 release];
```

str2 is what u want

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple. First you must break up the characters into an array to work with. Then you swap the letters X many times, I choose to do this so every character will be swapped

```
NSString *str =@"abcdefg123";
int length = str.length;
NSMutableArray *letters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i< length; i++) {
    NSString *letter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [str characterAtIndex:i]];
    [letters addObject:letter];
}

for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    int value = arc4random() % (length-1);
    NSLog(@"Value is : %i", value);
    [letters exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:value];
}

NSString *results = [letters componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"The string before : %@", str);
NSLog(@"This is the string now : %@", results);
```